# How to get the best perfomance in Google Script?

Tags: performance, google-apps-script

As you might know, Google gives only 1 hour of execution time for triggered scripts (web-apps and manual calls are not in this hour).
I hadn't found a good explanation of how to boost script perfomance, so I had to find out it myself. Here's what helped me:

Answer (score 1):

### 10 tips & tricks to get the best perfomance in Google Script

There is an official Google's [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices) documentation on how to write scripts. However it's not that comprehensive and misses some important tips and explanations, which you will additionally find here.

1. Use as less as possible time consuming methods.
   Any method which is **considered as time-consuming** by Google you will always find in the execution report [image] .
   Some examples of time-consuming methods:

   - Methods, which read/save information to the Sheet: `getValue`, `getValues`, `getDisplayValue`, `getRangeByName`, `getSheet`, `setValue`, `deleteRow` etc. Some consume more, some less.
   - Methods, using other external services, like `GmailApp`, `Utilities` etc.
   - Document/Script properties (but they are a somewhat faster than getting data from sheet).
2. If you use Libraries, don't forget to create a new version of the library, when you finish coding, and switch off developer mode in you calling scripts (*sorry for non-English screenshots*). In my case it **speeded up** the dummy script launches (when the script got a signal, that it should stop) **by 3 times**.
   [image]
3. The parts of code, which are non included into any function, and can be executed conditionally must be grouped into initialization functions and called when a condition is met. This actually can be applied to any part of code. The thing is that the code, which is located outside of any function, is always executed, whether it's in your basic project or in a library.
4. Use Batch operations when possible. One `getValues()` on 100 cells is much faster then 100 `getValue()` on each cell. Same for `deleteRows()` and `setValues()` etc.
5. If you use many script/document properties, use batch methods also.
6. If you use many static Named Ranges, create a cache for all of them and make an object (hash array) from that. Make a refreshing procedure and use it when required. My project has 137 named ranges: this point had a huge effect.
   [image]
7. Avoid `sleep` method, if possible.
8. Google advises to [use cache for web pages](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices) with fetchUrl (if applicable).
9. Google advises to avoid Library usage in [UI heavy scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices) (e.g. when you use triggers based on Google Sheet actions).
10. If your triggered script isn't supposed to work 24 hours make a work schedule for it and route your script to a lightweight procedure.
    *Example:*

```js
if ((new Date()).getHours() < 9) {
  var TriggeredEveryMinuteFunction = function() {
    //...do some lightweight stuff or nothing...
  }
} else {
  function TriggeredEveryMinuteFunction() {
    //  ...do some heavy stuff...
    func2();
  }

  function func2() { /*some more stuff*/ }
  var func3 = function() { /*some more stuff*/ }
  var etc() { /*some more stuff*/ }
}
```

In this example functions `func2`,`func3`,`etc` are **not compiled** when it's less than 9 o'clock.
If you try to call them, you'll get "not found" message.

Comment: apps script has an official page that mentions this. it has a few more tips.

Comment: @ZigMandel Are you sure? If it's a link other than in point 8, post it here.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices would have saved you some time :)

Comment: @ZigMandel then you are wrong. There's only one more tip regarding UI heavy scripts (which I decided to omit here), but point 8 has a link to that document.

Comment: Ok, I should have said "some of this". for example it has the tip about getting data in ranges. There is overlap, Im not saying your tips arent useful, but you should have started from that page and add to it.

Comment: @ZigMandel read carefully both docs (this post and google's) and you'll find the difference and some new tips here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132849/discussion-between-nikiton-and-zig-mandel).

Comment: I have (read my profile :) and I stand by saying that your answer should start by the official google documentation, which already states several of your tips and has extra tips as well. You seem to have missed it from what you say in your question about having to find them all by yourself.

Comment: @ZigMandel I've adde point 9 which was missing here and changed the header, where I mentioned the info regarding Google's best practises.